# html5 video seek, very slow

Tags: html, video

I've made a html5 video player, and I've noticed that the seeking times are freakishly long if the current video playing is somewhat large.

The closer towards the end I seek, the longer the seeking time; independent on if I've been there before/how close to the point I am in the current time or if I've buffered the whole video.

This can take as much as 15 seconds on a slow browser with a 1080p video when I seek to about 2 minutes into the video.

Is this normal or have I done something horribly wrong? *and can I do something about it*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which browser? Different browsers support different video formats and codecs.
Also, the HTML5 video element use GPU hardware acceleration so the performances are really dependant on the hardware

Comment: Well Chrome is about 3 times faster than the others, it's still about 6 or so seconds though. And I'm on the fattest iMac, to the hardware shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: In that case the hardware shouldn't be an issue. I doubt you can do something about it. By the way have you tested different videos?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm wondering if it might be something with the encoding, gonna test a different video asap. By the way, are there any known differences in speeds between mp4, webm and ogv?

Comment: Yes it was the encoding, tested another video, and it's blazing fast. Thanks for the help Toni

Comment: I can't help with the speed. Good idea trying with a different encoding, the file you are using might simply be an "unlucky" one.

Comment: It seems as if firefox plays the webM format extremely poorly. I cant tell who the villain is, firefox or the WebM format...

Comment: It's the WebM format, OGV runs smooth as #&@!
It's strange though, I thought WebM was the new kid on the block that was to be used over the others... Guess I was mistaken